# How to implement a scroll view in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My goal is to have 4 boxes. At any given point only 3 boxes will be visible, while 1 will be hidden. Then if you scroll left or right you will reveal the fourth box/hide the first box. Basically a simple scroll view. I'm planning on implementing this on Pygame.
I understand this is a relatively empty question; I'm looking for a library or general idea to implement this. Any recommendations?

Comment: create bigger surface with all boxes and in window display only part of this surface to show only three boxes..

Comment: Yes, but how do you handle the scrolling part, like how do you detect that the user is scrolling left/right?

Comment: normally use `offset_x` to decide which part of full surface display in window. As for detecting user scrolling: first learn PyGame and you will know it. In every tutorial you will see how to get keyboard events.

Comment: I know pygame, I've used it before. When I mention scrolling, I mean mouse moving across the screen scrolling. Not the mouse scroll-wheel scrolling.

Comment: if you know pygame then you should know event `MOUSEMOTION`

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks for mentioning that. Ill look it up. Thanks!

Comment: in documentation you have all [events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html). in yellow rectangle. There is `MOUSEMOTION` and `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` if you want to scroll only when you click button

Comment: Is there a way to detect if the mouse moved from left to write, or do I need to manually code that out by storing the prior mouse x,y in a list and seeing the change?

Comment: see `MOUSEMOTION` in doc - it has `event.rel` which means relative position and you can recognize how much it moved since previous `MOUSEMOTION`

Comment: BTW: in [python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples) I have little more complex version which scroll image when you click buttons on pseudo-scrollbars. [scrolling-mouse.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/scrolling-image)

Comment: Thanks! Ill take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created code which move images when you move mouse (without clicking button)

I use `camera_rect` to keep `offset` used to move image.

I use event `MOUSEMOTION` and `event.rel` to change value in `camera_rect`

It was created for image 800x600 and window 400x300 and it moves full image but for different sizes it may need different calculations - or it may need to calculate mouse position as percentage and use this percentage to calculate image position.

```
import pygame

# === CONSTANS === (UPPER_CASE names)

#BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
#WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

#RED   = (255,   0,   0)
#GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
#BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 400
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 300

# === CLASSES === (CamelCase names)

    # empty
    
# === FUNCTIONS === (lower_case names)

    # empty
    
# === MAIN === (lower_case names)

# --- (global) variables --- 

# --- init ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# --- objects ---

image = pygame.image.load('image-800x600.jpg')
image_rect = image.get_rect()

# --- camera / offset ---

camera_rect = screen_rect.copy()

# --- mainloop ---

#button_pressed = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:

    # --- events ---
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # --- global events ---
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
            
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                is_running = False

        #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        #    button_pressed = True
        #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        #    button_pressed = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            #if button_pressed:
    
                camera_rect.x += event.rel[0]
                # check left/right limit
                if camera_rect.left < image_rect.left:
                    camera_rect.left = image_rect.left
                if camera_rect.right > image_rect.right:
                    camera_rect.right = image_rect.right
    
                camera_rect.y += event.rel[1]
                # check up/down limit
                if camera_rect.top < image_rect.top:
                    camera_rect.top = image_rect.top
                if camera_rect.bottom > image_rect.bottom:
                    camera_rect.bottom = image_rect.bottom
                    
        # --- objects events ---

    # --- updates ---

        
    # --- draws ---
    
    #screen.fill(BLACK)

    # draw image
    screen.blit(image, (-camera_rect.x, -camera_rect.y))
    #screen.blit(image, camera_rect)

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- FPS ---

    clock.tick(25)

# --- the end ---
    
pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:**

More universal version which use pecentage to calculate position.

```
import pygame

# === CONSTANS === (UPPER_CASE names)

#BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
#WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

#RED   = (255,   0,   0)
#GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
#BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 400
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

# === CLASSES === (CamelCase names)

# empty
    
# === FUNCTIONS === (lower_case names)

# empty
    
# === MAIN === (lower_case names)

# --- (global) variables --- 

# --- init ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# --- objects ---

image = pygame.image.load('image-800x600.jpg')
image_rect = image.get_rect()

# --- camera / offset ---

camera_rect = screen_rect.copy()

percentage_x = 0
percentage_y = 0

# --- mainloop ---

#button_pressed = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:

    # --- events ---
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # --- global events ---
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
            
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                is_running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            percentage_x = event.pos[0] / screen_rect.width
            camera_rect.x = percentage_x * (image_rect.width - screen_rect.width)

            #percentage_y = event.pos[1] / screen_rect.height
            #camera_rect.y = percentage_y * (image_rect.height - screen_rect.height)
                    
        # --- objects events ---
        
        # empty
        
    # --- updates ---

    # empty
        
    # --- draws ---
    
    #screen.fill(BLACK)

    # draw image
    screen.blit(image, (-camera_rect.x, -camera_rect.y))
    #screen.blit(image, camera_rect)

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- FPS ---

    clock.tick(25)

# --- the end ---
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I added code which use percentages to calculate position.